# AWS S3 list keys begins with a string

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using python in AWS Lambda function to list keys in a s3 bucket that begins with a specific id

```
for object in mybucket.objects.all():
            file_name = os.path.basename(object.key)
            match_id = file_name.split('_', 1)[0]
```

The problem is if a s3 bucket has several thousand files the iteration is very inefficient and sometimes lambda function times out

Here is an example file name

```
https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/bucket-name/012345_abc_happy.jpg
```

i want to only iterate objects that contains "012345" in the key name
Any good suggestion on how i can accomplish that

Comment: This question repeatedly uses the word **contains** when it appears to mean **begins with.** That is a very important distinction, since the accepted answer is only correct for *begins with* -- which is a subset of *contains*.  S3 supports only prefix match (begins with) and not string match (contains) key listings.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Is that feature limitation still the case 3 years later? I also would like to search through keys, but my string of interest is in the middle, not the end.

Comment: @user554481 scanning the keyspace is not supported and that's what would be required to look for a match in the middle of object keys. Think of a telephone directory.  Try to find someone in such a book by their first name (not last), and you immediately see the nature of the problem.

Comment: I could see how that would be taxing for AWS to do a full table scan of its keys, but isn't that what often happens anyways when a user like OP has to scan all of the objects through a rest API and perform a text search on all the keys on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you need to solve it.

S3 stores everything as objects and there is no folder or filename. It is all for user convenience.

> aws s3 ls s3://bucket/folder1/folder2/filenamepart --recursive

will get all s3 objects name that matches to that name.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucketname')
for obj in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='012345'):
    print(obj)
```

To speed up the list you can run multiple scripts parallelly.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve speed by 30-40% by dropping `os` and using string methods.
Depending on the assumptions you can make about the file path string, you can get additional speedups:

Using `os.path.basename()`:

```
%%timeit
match = "012345"
fname = "https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/bucket-name/012345_abc_happy.jpg"
os.path.basename(fname).split("_")[0] == match

# 1.03 µs ± 29.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Without `os`, splitting first on `/` and then on `_`:

```
%%timeit
match = "012345"
fname = "https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/bucket-name/012345_abc_happy.jpg"
fname.split("/")[-1].split("_")[0] == match

# 657 ns ± 11.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

If you know that the only underscores occur in the actual file name, you can use just one `split()`:

```
%%timeit
match = "012345"
fname = "https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/bucket-name/012345_abc_happy.jpg"
fname.split("_")[0][-6:] == match

# 388 ns ± 5.65 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```